# Amazon Advanced FPS programming tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm struggling to find any good library for Amazon FPS for Ruby language, and so
I'm looking for a suggestion on a good explanation (other than amazon docs) or perhaps a tutorial to get me up to speed quickly with Amazon FPS.

What I am looking for is information on how to set up user registration form and do recurring payments which vary in amount charged to the user.

I've already wasted 4 hours going through amazon docs and received a lot of errors when sticking to their information, and the only result I got is getting hungry.

As a side note, I've set up sandbox business account and Amazon keeps notifying me that I did not set up sandbox business account.

Could someone possibly please redirect me to some insightful resources on using Amazon FPS but different than *crappy* sample FPS apps, and twisted amazon documentation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a Ruby Library called Remit for working with Amazon Flexible Payment Service (FPS) and a blog post with someone's experiences working with it and some samples. I'm new to Stack Overflow and not allowed to use hyperlinks yet :)  but if you search RubyForge for "remit" and google for the string "Software as a Service with Amazon FPS using Remit for Ruby" you should be able to find them.  Find it [here](http://edgenic.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/software-as-a-service-with-amazon-fps-using-remit-for-ruby/).